# Duplicated results in JPA Repository

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA Repository for my *Document* entity. And I have a problem with one long method, where I want to achieve something like full text search across multiple tables. *Document* Entity has some *OneToMany* relationships.

```
public interface DocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<Document, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Document> {
    Page<Document> findByInstanceNumberContainingIgnoreCaseOrAttachmentsNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrDocumentIdEqualsOrHeaderAuthorNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrCommentsCommentContainingIgnoreCaseOrFormFieldsSvalueContainingIgnoreCaseOrItemListsRowsCellsSvalueContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByInstanceNumber(Pageable pageable, String instanceNumber, String attachmentName, Integer documentId, String authorName, String comment, String formContent, String cellContent);
}
```

Unfortunately, that method returns multiplied and duplicated results. For example, currently I have 120 records in my *Documents* table, but I am getting 10485638 results in this query.

Here is something what was generated and used to fetch results

```
select count(document0_.id) as col_0_0_ from documents document0_ left outer join attachments attachment1_ on document0_.id=attachment1_.document_id left outer join headers header2_ on document0_.header_id=header2_.id left outer join authors author3_ on header2_.author_id=author3_.id left outer join comments comments4_ on document0_.id=comments4_.document_id left outer join form_fields formfields5_ on document0_.id=formfields5_.document_id left outer join item_list itemlists6_ on document0_.id=itemlists6_.document_id left outer join rows rows7_ on itemlists6_.id=rows7_.item_list_id left outer join cells cells8_ on rows7_.id=cells8_.row_id where upper(document0_.instance_number) like upper('%TEST%') escape '\' or upper(attachment1_.name) like upper('%TEST%') escape '\' or document0_.external_document_id=123 or upper(author3_.name) like upper('%TEST%') escape '\' or upper(comments4_.comment) like upper('%TEST%') escape '\' or upper(formfields5_.svalue) like upper('%TEST%') escape '\' or upper(cells8_.svalue) like upper('%TEST%') escape '\''
```

What can I do to fix that issue and get only unique documents? I need paging, so I can not use Set here.

Edit:
*Document* Entity class (without getters, setters and constructors):

```
@Entity
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "documents", indexes = {
        @Index(columnList = "external_document_id", unique = true),
        @Index(columnList = "instance_number")
})
public class Document {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "documents_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="documents_generator", sequenceName = "documents_seq", allocationSize=50)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "external_document_id", nullable = false, unique=true)
    private Integer documentId;

    @Column(name = "version", nullable = false)
    private Integer version;

    @Column(name = "instance_number", nullable = false)
    private String instanceNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    private Task tasks;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "header_id")
    private Header header;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Comment> comments = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Attachment> attachments = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<FormField> formFields = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<ItemList> itemLists = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: Can you add the `Document` entity class to the question?

Comment: You should think about to simplify you JPA repository function name and use Query annotations in this case.

Comment: You should consider creating a projection class, to fetch only needed columns as shown [here](https://wesome.org/spring-data-jpa-projections).

Comment: The fact that you have a massive method name already quite indicates you shouldn't be doing this. Write a proper JPQL query instead and make sure it is using `DISTINCT` on the main object you want. Next you should be including a proper `equals` and `hashCode` method (see https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/) for all your entities (use the identifier not the lombok generated equals!). Your current apprach returns **#documents*#comments*#attachements*#formfields*#itemlists** number of rows, due to the way you are querying.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum , Manuel and birca123. I will try to simplify that. I started trying to write pure SQL query, maybe it will works.

Comment: You don't need a SQL query a JPQL will do.